# Can't find htdocs after installing lampp in ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: apache2, lamp

I've installed lampp in Ubuntu 18.04, following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNwCGttYrlM).

Everything works fine, but I want to know where to put my project folders. In school we put them in `htdocs` which is inside `/opt`, but I coudn't find it there.

I am wondering if I have to create it manually? Or is it somewhere else? I only have 2 folders inside `/opt` : `google` and `pt`.

Any help would be great :)

NOTE: I can access phpmyadmin and create tables and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Try `/var/www/html` instead.... That works here!